# hide columns based on user input cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

hi all (I am new to scripting),

here is a sample of my sheet I need help with.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iypkWdUsSkow9m8nTSFS25HgY1d5vsVMZvjEynwQJcM/edit?usp=sharing

what i need is a script that will run onedit.

the user has 5 selectable fields, highlighted in yellow.  the script should run only if cell F3 is edited.

and what it should do is hide all column where row 1 does not match F3.

please please help!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this small function that hides or unhides columns depending on the value of the dropdown in `F3`, and that only runs when this cell is modified.

Copy this to the script bound to your spreadsheet:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source; // Spreadsheet that triggered the function
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Change accordingly
  var range = e.range; // Range that was edited
  var editedColumn = range.getColumn();
  var editedRow = range.getRow();
  var column = 6;
  var row = 3;  
  // Check that the edited cell is F3 and the edited sheet is the one you want:
  if(column == editedColumn && row == editedRow && sheet.getName() == sheetName) {
    var dropdownValue = range.getValue(); // Value of F3
    // Index of last column with content. If you want to hide the blank columns after that, use sheet.getMaxColumns() instead:
    var cols = sheet.getLastColumn();
    // First row values:
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, cols).getValues()[0];
    // Looping through each column (hiding or unhiding depending on whether value matches):
    for(var i = 1; i < cols; i++) {
      if(headers[i] != dropdownValue) {
        sheet.hideColumns(i + 1);
      } else {
        sheet.showColumns(i + 1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please tell me if that works for you.

Comment: so VERY close but there are some anomalies.  If you go to the sheet and you select CPR from the F3 drop down, column AD is still showing even though in row 1 you can see that column has TB in it.  Also, if you select TB, you can see that some columns without TB are still visible (P, AA, AG).  Same if CLASS B is selected, columns T and AG are visible but shouldn't be.  thank you for what you have done, hoping you have a moment to look at the issues?   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LyQmy36JfFyBJPCjB8GN18RBuQCYsTpf3oIIGXRNONc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @TonySilveira, true. There was a really small problem with the index used when hiding/showing columns (`sheet.hideColumns(i)` should be `sheet.hideColumns(i + 1)`, and the same for `showColumns`). Now I checked and it's hiding exactly what it has to hide, no exceptions. See if that works for you now.

Comment: Awesome!  Working like a charm, thank you so much!  If I may, one more question?  I'm playing with the sheet to make it a bit more user friendly.  So, instead of the user picking CPR/TB/CLASS B in a drop down, cell F3 as referenced in the script, Cell F3 is now formula driven, here is the formula:  =ifs(I3="YES","TB",I5="YES","CPR",I7="YES","CLASS B").  But now the script doesn't seem to like F3, I think it sees it as a formula and not the text that gets outputted.  So, id there anything to put into the script that forces it to look at the formula output and not the formula?

Comment: It's not a problem of the script getting the formula and not the value. The issue is that the edited cell is not F3 anymore, so it is not using the value of F3 to hide/unhide columns. The script should be modified a bit to accomplish this, but this is not what you wanted to do in the original question, so I'd recommend you to post another question with your current issue, and mark this question as solved by [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that solved your original issue.